# Is this a memory leak in a Sharepoint Workflow application?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I'm referring to the `ParentWeb` property on a list that is set through the `onWorkflowActivated` Activity within a Sharepoint Workflow something like this:

```
return new ContractManagementRepository(
    this.onWorkflowActivated_WorkflowProperties.List.ParentWeb);
```

Since the workflow engine created the list instance does that mean that they are responsible for disposing it as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that [SPList.ParentWeb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.parentweb.aspx) is in the [SPDisposeCheck Do Not Dispose Rules](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rogerla/archive/2010/12/13/announcing-spdisposecheck-v14-0-4762-1000-update-for-sharepoint-development.aspx), so, no, `ParentWeb` does not need to be disposed.

The long answer from [SPList.ParentWeb Leaks Revisited](http://solutionizing.net/2009/01/09/splist-parentweb-leaks-revisited/) is the `ParentWeb` only needs to be disposed in usual circumstances:

> Only in the exceptional case that the list’s ParentWebUrl indicates it doesn’t live with its parent collection will a new SPWeb be created. I believe it is this exception, rather than the norm

Based on what you've shown, your workflow does not fit this case, so `ParentWeb` probably should not be disposed.